# Uppercase instead of lowercase Greek letter shown in Julia mode

Tags: unicode, characters

I am writing Julia code in Emacs, which allows the use of unicode characters in the source code. However, some symbols come out looking weird. For example the Greek letter [nu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nu_(letter)):

[image]

becomes:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this to be the correct lowercase nu letter?

Comment: What does Emacs say the character information is if you run `C-u C-x =` (which is the `what-cursor-position` command) with the point on that character?

Comment: `Char: C-j (10, #o12, #xa) point=4118 of 4204 (98%) column=7`

Comment: `C-j (10)` is a newline.  You surely want the *previous* character.

Comment: ... and add the information to the question: comments can disappear.

Comment: You don't say at all how you get that character in the buffer. Are you inserting it by name, using `C-x 8 RET <the name>`? If so, just what name are you using?

Comment: @Drew I believe that Julia Mode looks for the escaped name of certain common symbols and then replaces them with their proper unicode character (e.g. `\nu` gets replaced with `ν`). There's a file (`julia-mode-latexsubs.el`) in the Julia Mode source that makes a hashtable of these mappings; the most recent version seems to have the correct mapping for `\nu`. I wanted to see what the character was that got inserted (in the second screenshot) to see if the correct character is being substituted or if it is just a font issue (or something of a similar nature).